# What is the last integer in this sequence?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

Here are the first several entries in a finite sequence of integers.

$$ 31, 45, 71, 89, 91, 94, 111, 112, 118, 121, 126, 131, $$
$$ 134, 135, 139, 143, 144, 145, 148, 158, 161, 189, 193, 194, \dots $$

Your challenge is to identify the sequence, and **give its final entry.**

**________**
<sub>*Let me ([again](/questions/51945/what-is-the-next-integer-in-this-sequence)) state for the record that I know **[What (Not) To Do](http://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do)** in a Number Sequence Puzzle. There should be enough information provided here to make this sequence puzzle uniquely solvable.*</sub>

Comment: You have cleverly avoided alphabetical numerals.

Comment: It is a monotone increasing sequence of integers and thus it must converge to infinity!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The final entry is

> 2325

Reasoning:

> Converting A=1,Z=26 for the first few we get:
>  CA   31
>  DE   45
>  GA   71
>  HI   89
>  IA   91
>  ID   94
>  These are US state abbreviations, so 111 must be AK.
>  They are sorted in ascending numerical order, so running all 50 states through this method, the largest and last ends up as WY (Wyoming) = 2325.
>  (We know it's 50 because DC, Guam, etc. are excluded from the given list.)

An aside:

> The 'hint' here (that I didn't notice until I wrote this up) is "let me *state*"...

Comment: Let me state that this answer is 100% correct. :)