# Find how this finite sequence completes

Tags: cipher, pattern, lateral-thinking

> 7  14  31  51  70  81 104 107 129 149 155 175
> 192 215 238 259 279
>
> 299 301 301 314 328 350 372

Inspired by the discussion with the author of, and the clues to its solution are in that discussion: [What is the last integer in this sequence?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120163/what-is-the-last-integer-in-this-sequence)

I have constructed a finite (terminating), non decreasing sequence (I purposefully allowed this and not strictly increasing) that has a unique solution.

Not only is the solution unique, but it has a strong personal meaning for me.

I first intended to give the solution here immediately, as I very much doubt that it will be found, part of the challenge is to find the reason it is the unique solution.

However before posting it, I decided to let it run for a while as an open question first.

Comment: The text is very short. Are you sure I can uniquely decipher it without knowing the key?

Comment: I've confirmed the uniqueness claim, within the limits of google.  Will cross check with other search engines over next few days too.

Comment: I just checked with the other big 3 search engines, three find the means to identify the "larger strategy" I believe, but only one hit using one SE that finds the actual solution.  This must be one of the harder puzzles, after finding the mechanics of the puzzle (this is not the hard part), you have to find the right search engine and the right "public key" (in a loose sense) to find the sequence completion. So that's a nice challenge - existence can be established a bit easier than to find the solution. A worthy puzzle as my ice breaker I hope.

Comment: You should [contact staff](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/contact) and ask for your old account to be merged with your new one, which will allow you to comment on the question again rather than having to post them as answers.

Comment: In addition to @F1Krazy's comment, you may want to sign up first using one account. Both your accounts are unregistered. And probably you will be able to merge those accounts yourself using the contact form provided above (There is merge account option listed).

Comment: Since you mentioned finding the key on google, does that mean it simply can't be deciphered without knowing it? Sure, the puzzle as you imagine it has a unique solution, but from my point of view it looks like a simple substitution whose length is below the [unicity distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance) for simple substitutions.